# Xamarin forms Application retains SQLite Database even after App is Uninstall and Installed even after manifest is configures to AllowbackUp to false

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a offline Xamarin form Application where I save all the data in SQLite for which I am using [praeclarum/
sqlite-net]

and here is how I create My Database

```
        SqlDataStore.CreateSharedDataStore(
            Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
                    ),
                DataStoreConstants.DatabaseName
                )
            );
```

This is how I have configured my Manifest

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:replace="allowBackup" android:allowBackup="false"
```

I am trying to implement a functionality where SQLite Database should get deleted on Application Uninstalling for which I added android:allowBackup="false" still the database and data inside it retrieves after the Application is Uninstalled and installed back

Also I would Appreciate if someone can help me with what would be good approach to keep my database path right now I am using `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`
other Options which I can see for path are

```
        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data
        //     for the current roaming user.
        ApplicationData = 26,

        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data
        //     that is used by the current, non-roaming user.
        LocalApplicationData = 28,

        // Summary:
        //     The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data
        //     that is used by all users.
        CommonApplicationData = 35,
```

Comment: I dont think you need to have `tools:replace` here. Delete backup manually from google drive once before trying again just to make sure.

Comment: Try using `Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` .See here [Location mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/)

Comment: Is SqlDataStore.CreateSharedDataStore your own method? Since I didn't find this method in SQLite-net, it would be better to post this method out as well, also, application specific data(including database) you put in internal storage will be deleted when app uninstall by default, usually you don't need to configure allowBackup to false.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.LocalApplicationData` maps to `INTERNAL_STORAGE/.local/share` . `allowBackup` works only for application specific data. 
Xamarin.Essentials has specific APIs to use App specific directory.

Use `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory+ "sqlite"` to store your SQLite
[Xamrin.Essentials.FileSystemHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)